# How to select columns from 1 specific table from a query that joins across several tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008:

I only want the columns selected from the first table that I'm joining across.

IE

```
select * from device d, policy p
where d.deviceid = p.deviceid and p.name = 'hello'
```

Rather than select *, I want to dynamically select all the columns from the device table. I don't want to hard code them in the case that a column is added to the device table.

(Side note: this isn't at all my query, don't worry about implicit vs explicit joins unless it affects the select clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select d.* 
from device d, policy p
where d.deviceid = p.deviceid and p.name = 'hello'
```